# On page load check a radio button based on its id using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want on page load to check a radio button by default using pure javascript.
Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
var radioman = document.getElementById("btn-Man").value;
radioman.checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input required="required" type="radio" id="btn-Man" name="gender" value="1" class="radio-class">
<label for="btn-Man">Man</label>

<input required="required" type="radio" id="btn-Woman" name="gender" value="2" class="radio-class">
<label for="btn-Woman">Woman</label>
```

but it doesn't work. On page load the first radio button with the id="btn-Man" should be checked. What in the world i 'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without '.value' like:

```
var radioman = document.getElementById("btn-Man");
radioman.checked = true;
```

Comment: Yeah it worked. Why is it wrong using the value?

Comment: @designer When you include the value, your variable will now hold the value and you'll lose the reference to the element thus changing the element's value is not possible

Answer (score 1):

No need for variable assignment. Just change it's value on load.
You also don't need to get it's value.

When you include the value, your `variable` will hold the `value` of the element selected and you'll lose the reference to the `element` thus changing the element's value is not possible

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("btn-Man").checked = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the .value on setting the variable

```
window.onload = function() {
   var radioman = document.getElementById("btn-Man");
   radioman.checked = true;
}
```